# May I ask after I add quantity how I can link all all data to another datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I face a problem is how I can link all data information after I insert apple product quantity. For example I insert apple product it have 5 quantity after I add 5 it will become 10 it will show product apple 10 quantity. Now my code is just shows 10 quantity only it will not show product apple 10 quantity

```
Private Sub loadTransactions(ByVal transactionid As Integer)

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    'open connection if it is not open yet
    cnn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT s.cid as [ID], c.CheckerName as item_name, " & _
                                        "s.CheckerName as [CheckerName], s.ShipQuantity as [StockQuantity], s.[Date] as [Date], s.CompanyName as [CompanyName], s.CheckerDetail as [CheckerDetail]" & _
                                        " FROM stock s left join checker c on c.cid = s.checkercid where s.checkercid = " & transactionid & " ORDER BY s.cid", cnn)

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stock([CheckerDetail]) " & "VALUES('" & Me.txtdetail1.Text & "')"

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns("item_name").HeaderText = "ItemName"
    'close connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

```
product     quantity  
apple          5  
              10
```

Comment: after insert you need run another select and then pass data to dgv, right?

Comment: I think you should call something `Requery` method to show changes in data source being done

Comment: @PeterKsenak yes but i don't know how to write the code.

Comment: @user11623273 you already have the code written.. just call select query once again after insert

Comment: No! The Sql Insert statement is just a property of a command. It is never executed.

Comment: You have all sorts of fields and aliases for fields in your Select statement but no where do I see product and quantity that you show in your sample data. How does this relate?

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep your database objects local so you can ensure that they are closed and disposed. Connections are precious resources. A `Using ... End Using` block will do this even if there is an error.
2. Don't open the connection until the last possible moment and close it as soon as you can. Pass the connection string to the constructor of the connection.
3. Pass the Sql string and the connection to the constructor of the command
4. Always use parameters to prevent Sql injection and make formatting the Sql string easier. In Access the names of the parameters don't matter. The order that they appear in the Sql string must match the order that they are added to the Parameters collection.
5. I think that you want to Update the apple record not Insert an entirely new record. You can do this in 2 different ways. One way is to Update the quantity field by adding a value to the existing value in the field. The other way is to Update directly with the new quantity.

```vb
Private Sub loadTransactions(ByVal transactionid As Integer)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT s.cid as [ID], 
                                              c.CheckerName as ItemName,
                                              s.CheckerName, 
                                              s.ShipQuantity as [StockQuantity], 
                                              s.[Date], 
                                              s.CompanyName, 
                                              s.CheckerDetail  
                                     FROM stock s left join checker c on c.cid = s.checkercid 
                                     WHERE s.checkercid = @transactionID 
                                     ORDER BY s.cid", cnn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("transactionID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = transactionid
            cnn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateStock(transactionid As Integer)
    Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update stock Set CheckerDetail = CheckerDetail + @detail WHERE checkercid = @transactionID;", cnn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@detail", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(txtdetail1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@transactionID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = transactionid
            cnn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks your code but after i add the code to my project it still face same issue. The quantity i new add on still show empty.My product still maintenance just my quantity can show other data column no success record on my second datagridview

Comment: What column in the stock table is the primary key? Is the value of transactionid the Primary Key?

Comment: the stock table primary key is the cid. Mary may i ask is on this code (Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string") ) on the connection string is i put my database connection link. Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=mydataX.mdb;")